# My svelte App is not working as i wanted to

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sveltekit

I'm providing you the code below, deleting tables (which are buttons) is not working as I want it to be. Even if it works randomly it messes up the array order and table names get messed up. What am I doing wrong?

As I explained things get messed when I try to delete tables.

What I'm trying to do is to add Button adds a table (a button), I will add the normal functionality later for now it just logs the clicked tables id.
When delete mode is true I want the table that is clicked to delete itself.

```
<script>
    let tables = [];
    let deleteMode = false;
    let tableCounter = 0;

    function toggleDeleteMode() {
        deleteMode = !deleteMode;
    }

function tableClick(id) {
    if(!deleteMode){
        // this is a placeholder for the table click event
    console.log(`Table with id ${id} was clicked`);
    }
    else{
    tableCounter--
    const tableIndex = tables.findIndex(table => table.id === id);
    tables.splice(tableIndex, 1);
    }
}

function createTable() {
    tableCounter++;
    const table = {
        id: tableCounter,
        name: "Table" + tableCounter
    }
    tables = [...tables, table]

}



</script>




    <div id="table-container">
        <button on:click={toggleDeleteMode}>Delete Mode</button>
        {#each tables as table, id}
        <button on:click={tableClick(table.id)} class={!deleteMode ? "table" : "tableDelete"} >{table.name}</button>

        {/each}
        <button on:click={createTable} class="add-table" type="button">+</button>
      </div>


<style>

  #table-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
    padding: 24px;
    gap: 24px;
  }
  .tableDelete{
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 16px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    resize: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .table {
    height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 16px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    resize: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  .add-table {
    height: 200px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 120px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.2s;
  }
  
  .add-table:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on:click={tableClick(table.id)}` should be `on:click={() => tableClick(table.id)}`

and you're missing that ['Assignments are reactive'](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive)

So you can either add the assignment of `tables` to itself after the modification

```
            const tableIndex = tables.findIndex(table => table.id === id);
            tables.splice(tableIndex, 1);
            tables = tables
```

or do it with this line

```
            tables = tables.filter(table => table.id !== id )
```

With the 'counter-id' method it's quite easy produce duplicate ids after deleting items.
Here

```
{#each tables as table, id}
```

`id` is actually the index, named `id`. If you want to use the id as key ([tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks)) it should be

```
{#each tables as table (table.id)}
```

which then will result in an error if there are multiple items with the same id. An alternative way to create one would be for example [randomUUID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID)

Comment: Thank you so much, yes you are right i didn't study enough i forgot about the first part you mentioned.